# I am creating figma plugin where i want to get cookies from a website but it shows this error how can i solve this

Tags: typescript, figma

[This is the error that i get. I am using js-cookie for getting cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktsk8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [Navigator.cookieEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/cookieEnabled) to check enabled cookie or not. If user disabled cookies on web site you can't read them.